# Probability of an event from three sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

I've been using this formula to get the answer:

> $P (A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Question:

If I'm right about using the formula above for this question, how can I do it step by step?

If I'm using a wrong formula, what's the right formula to use in this problem?

Here's the question/problem that I'm trying to solve so you can determine if I'm using the right formula:

> A computer centre has three printers $A$, $B$, and $C$, which print at different speeds. Programs are routed to the first available printer. The probability that a program is routed to $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $0.3$, $0.2$, and $0.5$, respectively. Occasionally, a printer will jam and destroy a printout. The probabilities that printers $A$, $B$, and $C$ will jam are $0.01$, $0.05$, and $0.04$, respectively. Your program is destroyed when a printer jams.

1). What is the probability that your program will be destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is conditional probability.

to get the probability, you need to find the summation of (probability of a preogram going throught the specifc printer) multiplied by the (probability of the jamming of that printer.

so the answer will be >(0.3)(0.01)+ (0.2)(0.05) +(0.5)(0.04)
                  =0.033

Comment: Oh yes, this is right. PO = P(A)P(O/A) + P(B)P(O/B) + P(C)P(O/C). A conditional probability. That's the formula. I calculated it in calculator and the result is 0.033, not 0.023.

Comment: I edited that. Thanx